Multiple YAML files distributed throughout all branches?
I manage three branches: prod (the default branch), staging, and dev.
Feature branches stem from dev, then they're merged into staging before being merged into prod. To automate deployments, I've set up two separate GitHub Actions workflows: staging.yml and prod.yml.
My goal is for staging.yml to trigger automatically upon commits being merged into the staging branch, facilitating automatic deployment using staging.yml. Similarly, the prod branch should follow suit.
However, must these files exist on all branches? And do I need to keep updating all of them? For instance, if I make changes to these files on the dev branch, do I need to update both the staging file and the prod YAML files?
I currently have all files on all branches but it gets tedious to change the files on all branches if something in the YAML file changes.
